# rollup-plugin-typescript does not recognize 'lib' in 'compilerOptions'

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, rollupjs

I'm following [this tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-create-library-in-angular-2-and-publish-to-npm-from-scratch-f2b1272d6266) for creating an npm package.  Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
    },
    "files": ["./lib/empty-text.ts"]
}
```

When I run rollup I get this error:

```
rollup-plugin-typescript: Unknown compiler option 'lib'.
[!] Error: rollup-plugin-typescript: Couldn't process compiler options
Error: rollup-plugin-typescript: Couldn't process compiler options
    at typescript (D:\sandbox\rollup-play\node_modules\rollup-plugin-typescript\dist\rollup-plugin-typescript.cjs.js:226:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\sandbox\rollup-play\rollup.config.umd.js:45:9)
```

When I remove `lib` from `compilerOptions`, I get a different set of errors.  I'm using rollup v0.8.1.  Does this version not support `lib`, if it does, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you rsolved this error?

Answer (score 0):

It is not rollup itself that is complaining, but the typescript compiler that is called by the typescript plugin for rollout that you are apparently using. The rollup-plugin-typescript comes with Typescript 1.8.9 per default. The "lib" compiler option, however, was introduced in TS 2.0. So try using a sufficiently up-to-date TS version. According to https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-typescript#typescript-version you should do something like

```
typescript({
  typescript: require('some-fork-of-typescript')
})
```